# How to hide widget text on android?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I use the following code to update the text:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_counter, Long.toString(unreadRecordsCount));
```

but how can I hide it, if unreadRecordsCount = 0?

Comment: I've tried `views.setInt(R.id.widget_counter, "setVisibility", 0);` - it doesn't work.

Comment: `setBoolean` doesn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally familiar with `RemoteView`s but a quick check with the Android API gives this: [RemoteView#setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setViewVisibility%28int,%20int%29). I am assuming it works like a usual widget's setVisibility.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_counter, Long.toString(unreadRecordsCount));
if (unreadRecordsCount == 0) {
    views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_counter, View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Or View.GONE instead of INVISIBLE

Comment: `Viev.GONE` clean up the remaining space. Worked better then `View.INVISIBLE` in my case.